# Django - delete an object without deleting its related objects

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    some_field = models.CharField()

class Ticket(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
```

`Ticket`s are **FOREVER** in my system, but I want users to be able to delete clients they don't want anymore. Currently it'll delete all the tickets created by the `Client`.

1. Is this a bad idea (architecturally speaking), and should I just mark them as `not_needed` or something instead?
2. If it's not a bad idea, what's the best way to do it, while remaining DRY. I don't want to have to override `delete()` for each model that does this, but will if I have to (what's the best way to do that, if that's the only way).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So this question is very old but in case someone runs across it (like I did): starting from Django 1.3, you can use the `on_delete` parameter for `ForeignKey` models, as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete).

Comment: Yeah, 1.2 was the release way back when I answered.

Answer (score 6):

The `django.contrib.auth` module has to deal with this same problem in the `User` model.  Their solution is to have:

```
class User(models.Model):
    # ...
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    # ...
```

So "deleting" a `User` is just setting `is_active` to `False`.  Everything that works with `User`s needs to check `is_active`.

For the record, I think deleting `Client`s in this case is a **Bad Idea**.

But for the sake of argument, if you delete a `Client`, then its related `Ticket`s need to first become clientless.  Change the model for `Ticket` to:

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, null=True, blank=True, 
        related_name='tickets')
```

Then, to delete a `Client`, do:

```
for ticket in clientToDelete.tickets:
    ticket.client = None
    ticket.save()
clientToDelete.delete()
```

You can put this code into `Client`'s `delete` method, but it will get skipped if you do a mass (i.e. QuerySet-based) delete of `Client`s.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think it is a bad idea (you'd have orphan ticket records). I would just mark those clients as 'not_needed' or 'deleted'. You also get the added benefit of the ability to 'un-delete' those clients later.